# ¿Cómo instalar librerías según se las vaya necesitando?

Tags: r

Estoy con un proyecto de R, yo no toco codigo, lo que hago es poner etiquetas en el codigo de R, para que un script de C#, cambie el resultado que hay en las etiquetas por unas variables calculadas en mi script. En el script actual, necesito estas librerias

```
library(sp) 
library(raster)  
library(rgeos)  
library(magrittr)
```

Este es un ejemplo, segun avanzo con otros scripts, necesito otras, mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma, de que al ejecutar el script, reconozca que librerias necesita y las instale. Utilizo el RStudio.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Si, puedes, no es lo más recomendable ya que la instalación de un paquete debiera ser en una instancia más controlada y no en la de ejecución:

Remplazando `require("libreria")` o `library("libreria")` por esto:

```
if (!require("libreria")){install.packages("libreria");library("libreria")}
```

Se verifica si se puede cargar `"libreria"` en caso contrario, se la intenta instalar y cargar luego.

Consideraciones:

- Obviamente si tienes problemas para conectarte a los servidores oficiales, el paquete no podrá ser instalado
- En algunos casos dependiendo del sistema operativo, los paquetes descargados se compilan de forma local (linux), si no dispones de las herramientas y librerías de desarrollo para que R pueda hacerlo, obviamente fallará la instalación
- También esto esta restringido a los paquetes de CRAN, si necesitas instalar desde otras fuentes requerirás una forma distinta de instalación
- Esto te instalaría siempre la última versión del paquete, cosa que no es una muy buena práctica para producción al menos.

En mi opinión, lo óptimo es relevar todas las librerías que usan los scripts y hacer la instalación completa de las mismas previamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probare. Estoy haciendo un programa interno para la empresa, en la que quiero que segun se lea que librerias se necesitan, no sea el usuario el que las tenga que instalar. Gracias.